# Block/Proc with Include for Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to think of a way to do this as a proc.  Essentially the only part of the code that is different is that on substring match their is a .include? instead of a check for equals.

```
def check_exact_match(lead_attribute, tracker_attribute)
    return true if tracker_attribute.nil?
    return true if lead_attribute.downcase == tracker_attribute.downcase
    false
end


def check_substring_match(lead_attribute, tracker_attribute)
    return true if tracker_attribute.nil?
    return true if lead_attribute.downcase.include? tracker_attribute.downcase
    return false
end
```

Comment: Note that `return true if cond1; return true if cond2; false` can also be written as just `cond1 || cond2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I remember how to code in Ruby elegantly, but what about something like this?

```
def check­_match(lea­d_attribut­e, track­er_attribu­te)­
    track­er_attribu­te.nil? or yield lead_­attribute,­ track­er_attribu­te
end
```

The function can then be called like this:

```
check_match("abcd", "bd") { |l, t| l.downcase == t.downcase }
check_match(la, ta) { |l, t| l.downcase.include? t.downcase }
```

Comment: I know the OP said he wanted a proc, but this would be much more idiomatic if it used a block instead.

Comment: @sepp2k: I don't know, a block doesn't really stand for a predicate in my mind.

Comment: Lots of methods take a block as a predicate (`select`, `find`, `all?`, `any?`). I can't think of a single standard library method that takes a lambda/proc as a predicate (in fact the only standard library method that I can think of that takes a lambda at all is `Hash#default_proc=` and that's only because it would be syntactically impossible for it to take a block).

Comment: I edited my code to make use of your suggestion. What do you think about it now? :)

Comment: Idiomatic for expression is `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Modification from @busy_wait.

```
def check­_match(lea­d_attribur­e, track­er_attribu­te, &condition)­
  track­er_attribu­te.nil? or condition.­call(lead_­attribute,­ track­er_attribu­te)
end

def check_exact_match(lead_attribute, tracker_attribute)
  check_match(lea­d_attribur­e, track­er_attribu­te) { |l, t| l.downcase == t.downcase }
end

def check_substring_match(lead_attribute, tracker_attribute)
  check_match(lea­d_attribur­e, track­er_attribu­te) { |l, t| l.downcase.include? t.downcase }
end
```